# How to change the icon of an accordion immediately after onclick on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple accordion of bootstrap here its working fine,but I need to change the + and - icon immediately onclick,right now icon is changing only after total expand of panel body div.I need same thing in collapse also.Here is the code below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target).prev('.panel-heading').find(".more-less").toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  }
  $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
  $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container demo">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Collapsible Group Item #1
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to change $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
to 
$(document).on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hide.bs.collapse` and `show.bs.collapse` events instead of `hidden` and `shown` variants.

These events are fired as soon as the collapse gets triggered. Refer to the documentation here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#events

Answer (score 0):

Just change `hidden` by `hide` and `shown` by `show` like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  function toggleIcon(e) {
    $(e.target)
        .prev('.panel-heading')
        .find(".more-less")
        .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
  }
  
  $('.panel-group').on('hide.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
  $('.panel-group').on('show.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container demo">    
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <i class="more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                        Collapsible Group Item #1
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                      Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- panel-group -->
</div><!-- container -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With `show` the event fires immediately when the show instance method is called and with `hide` event is fired immediately when the hide method has been called.